# records that exist in the database that don't exist in the list

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have in database table **Gifts** with records, for example:

```
Id: 1, Name: A
Id: 2, Name: B
Id: 3, Name: C
```

In `IEnumerable<Gift> gifts` I have elements from user after modification, for example:

```
Id: 1, Name: A_update
Id: 3, Name: C_update
Id: 0, Name: D_new
```

Now I would like records that exist in the database that don't exist in the list - so in this example it should be one record:

```
Id: 2, Name: B
```

How can I do that because below code doesn't work:

```
List<Gifts> result = db.Gifts.Where(x => !gifts.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'MyProject.Models.Gift'.
>   Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this
>   context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of Entity Framework. In only supports using some specific data types in the expressions.

If you use Entity Framework 4.0 or later you can use this workaround:

```
int[] giftIds = gifts.Select(y => y.Id);
List<Gifts> result = db.Gifts.Where(x => !giftIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```